# Python argparse: nargs='?' and optional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Let's say I have a simple program called `readfile.py` which supports command line arguments by using Python's `argparse`.

The program reads from a file specified by the positional argument `input`. Without specifying additional arguments, this program is not very exciting. It *just* reads from `input` and exits. The optional argument `--output [OUTPUT_FILE]` signifies that the input file should be written to a file. `OUTPUT_FILE` is also optional. If it is not specified, the input should be written to `default.out`.

I set up my argument parser like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Read from a file')
parser.add_argument(
    'input',
    help='file to read from')
parser.add_argument(
    '--output',
    nargs='?',
    const='default.out',
    default=None,
    help="""write file to %(metavar)s. If %(metavar)s isn't
         specified, write file to %(const)s.""",
    metavar='OUTPUT_FILE')
args = parser.parse_args()
return args.file, args.output_file
```

Note I use `default=None` so that if `--ouput` doesn't appear on the command line, I can detect its absence with None.

Which gives a usage signature like this:

```
usage: readfile.py [-h] [--output [OUTPUT_FILE]] input
```

This handles arguments as expected if I run

```
python readfile.py input.in --output somefile.out
```

or

```
python readfile.py --output somefile.out input
```

It sets `output` to `default.out` if I run

```
python readfile.py input.in --output
```

but if I run

```
python readfile.py --output input.in
```

it complains about there being too few arguments. I thought argparse would be 'smart' enough to interpret this pattern, setting `input` to `input.in` and `output` to `default.out`. The generated usage even suggests this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this Q should at least leave a constructive hint in a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will not recognize this. You are in the last example clearly passing in `input.in` to `--output`.

I would recommend that you flip the `default` and the `const` parameters. You want the default to be default.out, so it should be `default='default.out'`. `const` can then be set to something else for the case of having an empty `--output` parameter.

That way you don't have to add the `--output` parameter unless you want to change the default, and you can use an empty `--output` parameter if you want to output to `stdout` for example.

Comment: In this case (confusingly?) `default` is used for no parameter after `--output` and `const` is used for the absence of the `--output` parameter altogether.

Comment: @eidorb: Yes, and that's backwards. Change it around. Use it as its supposed to be used.

Comment: I must apologise. My comment has it back to front, but my code has it the way I intended.

Comment: @eidorb: **And that is backwards**. Change it around. Use it as its supposed to be used. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass "--" to mark the end of any options.  For instance:

```
python readfile.py --output -- input
```

has the intended effect.  However, making the argument to --output required and allowing:

```
python readfile.py --output - input
```

is probably cleaner.